# Inconsistent ConfigurationManager behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wpf

I have learnt about custom configurations using the ConfigurationManager. For some reason you have to use the assembly reference in the section element of the app.config, otherwise the ConfigurationManager won't load the app.config. But in an ASP.NET app this works fine. Why?

Consider this custom configuration class:

```
namespace CustomConfiguration
{
    class MySection : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("link", IsKey = true)]
        public string Link
        {
            get => (string) this["link"];
            set => this["link"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Using this app.config, I can easily get the link-attribute of myCustomSection in my program:

```xml
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="myCustomSection" type="CustomConfiguration.MySection, myAssembly" />
  </configSections>

  ...

  <myCustomSection link="link i can access in my code" >
  </myCustomSection>


</configuration>
```

Removing the assembly reference in section-element of app.config will result in a ConfigurationErrorsException, because the ConfigurationManager can't load my CustomConfiguration.MySection class in it's own System.Configuration assembly. 
E.g.:

```xml
<section name="myCustomSection" type="CustomConfiguration.MySection" />
```

But [Microsofts documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms228245(v=vs.100)#example) says I should be able to do this.
And in fact I can do this in an ASP.NET app. Not supplying an assembly-name in a type attribute for a section still works and system.configuration magically looks in the right app assembly. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ASP.NET` hosting environment has a different assembly loading behaviour;
it loads all referenced assemblies (from then `bin` and `GAC`) at the moment of startup.
For that reason, the assembly of the `CustomConfiguration.MySection` section can be resolved automatically without specifying it in the `type` definition.

If you include the settings below in you `web.config` file, your assembly `myAssembly` will not be loaded at initial startup anymore.
Then it will also be required to specify the assembly part in the `type` definition via `CustomConfiguration.MySection, myAssembly`. Here you get the same behaviour as in a non web-based application.

```
<configuration>
    <!-- ... -->
    <system.web>    
        <compilation>           
          <assemblies>
              <remove assembly="myAssembly" />
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>
    </system.web>
    <!-- ... -->
</configuration>
```

---

The [referenced documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms228245(v=vs.100)#example) in your question shows that a section (shown belown) can be declared in an `app.config` file (of non web-based application), but this will only work for the out-of-the-box supplied configuration classes/handlers, like eg. `System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler`, which resides in the core `System` assemby (`System.dll`).
For all other (custom) sections, a full assembly-qualified name is required.

```
<configuration>
   <configSections>
      <section name="sampleSection"
               type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler" />
   </configSections>

   <sampleSection setting1="Value1" 
                  setting2="value two" 
                  setting3="third value" />
</configuration>
```